# Print number of copies depending on the textbox input and put page numbers C#

Tags: c#

Please help i am new to C# and i have a windows form with textbox1, textbox2, and buttom1 i would like to print the value of textbox1 without previewing or let me say straight to the printer without any interactions, textbox value has to be the number of capies i would love to print and also to page number all those copies say if i input 3 it should say page 1/3 2/3 3/3 please help and excuse my english
i have the following code under my button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("zed", 400, 850 );
        //printDocument.PrinterSettings.Copies = 2;
        printDocument.PrintPage += PrintDocumentOnPrintPage;
        printDocument.Print();
```

Comment: Look at `int.TryParse` - it returns true if converting a text value to an int was successful and false if it wasn't. You can take a textbox value and convert it to an integer to pass to .Copies :)

Comment: ok thanks alot John did converted it to and interger through a research as i state i am new to this stuff
            int i = 0;
            i = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            textBox2.Text = i.ToString();                  so passing it to .copies is a hussle to me as it says that i am implicitly passing int to short please help with how i can pass it to .copies

Answer (score 0):

i did solve the .copies problem but stil cannot solve the page numbering here is my code now under

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        short numCopies = 0;
        numCopies = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);


        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("zed", 400, 850 );
        printDocument.PrinterSettings.Copies = numCopies;
        printDocument.PrintPage += PrintDocumentOnPrintPage;
        printDocument.Print();

    }
```